# Angular ui-router add unique id to url on state change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

in angular 1.0 with ui-router, how can i add a unique id to each url on state change.

my_url/potato?uid=213123234234644

my_url/tomoto?uid=213123123123123
...

i tried with an interceptor:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q, myService) {
    return {
        'request': function (config) {
            config.url = config.url + '?uid=' + myService.getRandomUid();
            return config || $q.when(config);

        }

    }
});
```

this will not add it to the url shown in the browser. In my case i want it on the browser url and in history link also.

I see that we can use param in the route on angular ui-router but in this case i need to change all the routes of my apps. i try to avoid this huge change.

thank you for help

Comment: You might want to look at this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events

Comment: the solution is to add rootroute/?:uid to your root states url in each state hierarchy.
and add in params of these root states uid also.
at the end you can each time you change your state do:
$state.go(state_name, {uid: myService.generateUid());
it ll give you a unique id after each transition without changing all the routes in the app but only the root onces.

Comment: Nope, you can listen to the state changes, and then append your uid to your url, you don't have to do it on every single state (the event will be called regardless of which state is being transition to.) You will only need to do it in one place.

Comment: ok i ll try your suggestion as soon as possible and give you feedback